# What is com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.spi.c java agent?

Tags: java, tomcat8, agent, javaagents

Sorry if the question is too broad but if someone could explain me what is `com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.spi.c` and what's it purpose? 
I ask this question because I usually send my `.war` application to our hosting company and they proceed the installation on tomcat. There are 2 environments `staging` and `preproduction`.

I recently upgraded the JDK version of my application from 7 to 11 (adoptOpenjdk) and tomcat from 7 to 8.5 and the hosting company has some trouble to install it in `preproduction` while they succeded in `staging`.

When I took a look at tomcat's logs, I saw that exeption:

```
[Thread-4] Thu Feb 07 13:44:31 CET 2019[INFO]: AgentInstallManager - Full Agent Registration Info Resolver using node name [PWS]
[Thread-4] Thu Feb 07 13:44:31 CET 2019[DEBUG]: AgentInstallManager - Full Agent Registration Info Resolver finished running
[Thread-4] Thu Feb 07 13:44:31 CET 2019[INFO]: AgentInstallManager - Agent runtime directory set to [/opt/appdynamics/appagent/ver4.2.6.1]
[Thread-4] Thu Feb 07 13:44:31 CET 2019[INFO]: AgentInstallManager - Agent node directory set to [PWS]
[Thread-4] Thu Feb 07 13:44:31 CET 2019[INFO]: JavaAgent - Using Java Agent Version [Server Agent v4.2.6.1 GA #12852 rb165fa8df244b8369ae956b400e2ff834cf44edc 8-4.2.6.next-analytics]
[Thread-4] Thu Feb 07 13:44:31 CET 2019[INFO]: JavaAgent - Running IBM Java Agent [No]
[Thread-4] Thu Feb 07 13:44:31 CET 2019[INFO]: JavaAgent - Java Agent Directory [/opt/appdynamics/appagent/ver4.2.6.1]
[Thread-4] Thu Feb 07 13:44:31 CET 2019[INFO]: JavaAgent - Java Agent AppAgent directory [/opt/appdynamics/appagent/ver4.2.6.1]
Agent Logging Directory [/opt/appdynamics/appagent/ver4.2.6.1/logs/PWS]
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.singularity.ee.agent.configuration.k (file:/opt/appdynamics/appagent/ver4.2.6.1/lib/appagent-boot.jar) to field java.security.AccessControlContext.context
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.singularity.ee.agent.configuration.k
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Running obfuscated agent

Could not start Java Agent, Disabling !!!!!com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.spi.c: Could not start services ,Please check log files

com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.spi.c: Could not start services
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.l.start(l.java:124)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.JavaAgent.initialize(JavaAgent.java:428)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.JavaAgent.initialize(JavaAgent.java:242)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.AgentEntryPoint$1.run(AgentEntryPoint.java:481)
Caused by: com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.spi.e: Error starting service [TransactionMonitoringService]java.sql.SQLException
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.qc.a(qc.java:287)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.qc.a(qc.java:249)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.l.start(l.java:118)
        ... 7 more
```

My questions are:

- What is `JavaAgent : com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent`?
- What is it purpose?
- Why someone does need to use it?
- Why the application crashes at starting because of this agent?

I also took a look at agent logs and there are many many exceptions like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.singularity.asm501.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
        at com.singularity.asm501.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:150)
        at com.singularity.asm501.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:402)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.services.bciengine.asm501.d.a(d.java:443)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.services.bciengine.asm501.d.<init>(d.java:314)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.services.bciengine.asm501.gb.a(gb.java:372)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.services.bciengine.asm501.bb.a(bb.java:624)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.services.bciengine.asm501.bb.a(bb.java:893)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.services.bciengine.asm501.x.a(x.java:374)
        at com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.services.bciengine.asm501.x.transform(x.java:326)
        at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
        at java.base/java.lang.VMAccess.findClassOrNull(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1026)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendText(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:794)
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.<clinit>(DateTimeFormatter.java:1289)
        at org.hibernate.type.InstantType.<clinit>(InstantType.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.<init>(BasicTypeRegistry.java:60)
        at org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration.<init>(TypeConfiguration.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.BootstrapContextImpl.<init>(BootstrapContextImpl.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:124)
        at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:218)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:32)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:166)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:141)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$161.0000000034BF6AA0.getObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4792)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:629)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
[localhost-startStop-1] 07 Feb 2019 13:44:41,680 ERROR ClassMetaData - Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException caught trying to parse class file for java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$TextPrinterParser from ClassLoader boot
```

Thanks a lot for your clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an APM agent for appdynamics. If you do not know what it is, I doubt you need it.

Comment: Could you add more details. Personally I don't need it but I don't understand the purpose of this agent.

Comment: After some searches I understood the reason of this agent, is there a way to disable agent attachment on the JVM running starting my tomcat. I am using adoptOpenJDK11 + OpenJ9

Comment: Just remove it from the JVM parameters.